# Como crear secuencia de luces led con assembler?

Tags: ensamblador

Este es mi codigo, se supone que tengo que editar donde dice programa para que pueda encender los leds de tal manera que parezca un ping pong, estos estan conectados al puerto b de este pic 18f4550, pero solo lo supe hacer manual (cargando en w el valor del led, como se muestra en la imagen). He intentado usar la funcion RRNCF pero no me funciona. Soy nuevo en assembler...

```
LIST p=18f4550
INCLUDE <p18f4550.INC>

;------------------Register GPR SFR--------
PC      EQU 0FF9H ;Registro SFR PCL
STATUS  EQU 0FD8H ;Registro SFR status y flags

REG1    EQU 0100H ;Registro GPR 

CONTA1  EQU 0101H ;Registro GPR subrutina retardo
CONTA2  EQU 0102H ;Registro GPR subrutina retardo
CONTA3  EQU 0103H ;Registro GPR subrutina retardo

;------------------------------------------
        org 0000H
        GOTO CONFIG_PIC
;---------------------------------------------------------------
; SUBRUTINA DE RETARDO
;---------------------------------------------------------------
RETARDO     MOVLW   0FFH
        MOVWF   CONTA1 ; CONTA1=0FFH

CICLO3      MOVLW   0FFH
        MOVWF   CONTA2 ; CONTA2 = 0FFH

CICLO2      MOVLW   01H
            MOVWF   CONTA3; CONTA3 = 01H

CICLO1      DECFSZ  CONTA3,1 ;decrementa el contenido CONTA3
        GOTO    CICLO1

        DECFSZ  CONTA2,1 ;decrementa el contenido CONTA2
        GOTO    CICLO2

        DECFSZ  CONTA1,1 ;decrementa el contenido CONTA1
        GOTO    CICLO3
        RETURN
;---------------------------------------------------------------
; ACA PROGRAMA O ALGORISMO
;---------------------------------------------------------------
PROGRAMA

        MOVWF   PORTB ; PORTB=1
        RRNCF   PORTB,0
        MOVWF   PORTB
        CALL    RETARDO


        GOTO    PROGRAMA
;---------------------------------------------------------------
; CONFIGURACION DE LOS RECURSOS DE HARDWARE INTERNOS PIC 18F4550
;---------------------------------------------------------------
CONFIG_PIC  NOP
        CLRF    PORTB ;Al borrar y dejar el bit en 0 se configura como puerto de salida
        CLRF    LATB
        MOVLW   0EH
        MOVWF   ADCON1  ;REG SFR CONFIGURACION DE LOS PINES I/O COMO DIGITALES

        MOVLW   b'00000000'
        MOVWF   TRISB   ; REG SFR CON CEROS CONFIGURO EL PORTB COMO OUTPUT
        MOVLW   0080H
        GOTO    PROGRAMA
;--------------------------------------------------------------
END
```

Aqui esta como lo tenia manual (led por led):[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Según lo veo yo, estás empezando por 128 en decimal (80h) y vas dividiendo entre 2 (40h serían 64, 20h es 32...) Por lo que más que un incremento debes hacer una división entre 2 ( o desplazamiento a la derecha). No recuerdo cómo se hace en ensamblador de ese Pic, pero x ahí van los tiros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final lo logre hacer, solo hay que cargar un valor en el puerto b, esto lo hice agregando estas lineas en CONFIC_PIC, d significa que el numero es decimal, como se carga el valor 1 estamos agregando el valor al bit 0 (los bits van según las potencias de 2: 2^0=1, 2^1=2,etc)

```
MOVLW   d'1'
MOVWF   PORTB
```

si no se carga el valor se rotaran 0s y obviamente no prenderan los leds; ahora en programa solo rotamos ese bit a la derecha sin carry con el RRNCF, como se cargo en el bit 0 y esta rotando a la derecha empezara a verse encendido en el bit 7 (128 en decimal) (nota: o eso al menos me muestra la simulacion en proteus). luego se usa el BTFSC para verificar si el bit 0 tiene un valor de 1 o 0, si es 0 salta a PROGRAMA, si no va a MOVERIZQUIERDA, esto para dar el efecto que rebota como un ping pong. MOVERIZQUIERDA es lo mismo pero tiene RRLCF que ahora rota a la izquierda sin carry y nuevamente se verifica pero ahora el bit 7 si vale 1 o 0, si vale 1 simplemente se ejecuta todo desde 0.

```
PROGRAMA        
        GOTO    MOVERDERECHA
MOVERDERECHA
        RRNCF   PORTB,1
        CALL    RETARDO
        BTFSC   PORTB,0
        GOTO    MOVERIZQUIERDA
        GOTO    PROGRAMA
 MOVERIZQUIERDA
        RLNCF   PORTB,1
        CALL    RETARDO
        BTFSC   PORTB,7
        GOTO    PROGRAMA
        GOTO    MOVERIZQUIERDA
```

Si alguien encuentra errores o busca mejorar mi explicacion/codigo etc le agradeceria mucho :D